# How to flicker high-power LEDs with precise square or sine wave?

Tags: arduino, led, pwm, led-driver, wave

I need some advice regarding a setup with high-power LEDs I am currently working on.

My aim: I have a set of 6 high power LEDs (http://www.roithner-laser.com/datasheets/led_highsingle/apg2c3-530.pdf) that I need to flicker at different frequencies (between 20Hz-1kHz approximately) preferably with a sine or square wave and fixed 50% duty cycle while keeping the luminance constant. I also need to be able to set the frequency from a PC (e.g. using MATLAB).

My attempted solution so far has been to power the LEDs using a bench power supply unit and a customized circuit (schematic below) while controlling them from an Arduino. However, with this setup, **the wave is not square** and there’s an observable **change in luminance as a function of frequency** with higher frequencies resulting in lower luminance (oscilloscope luminance measurements below). I’ve tried the same code with a simpler circuit (a low power LED and a resistor connected directly to the Arduino) and I get the same results. I’ve also tried a different code using the TimerOne library, and the wave has the same shape, resulting in the same changes in luminance.

At this point, I'm considering switching to a different solution completely. Is there a different setup that would give more precise results?

Ideally, I would like to keep the cost low (less than $300), with some flexibility there; and as I don’t have any expertise in electronics, the simpler to set up the better. I've been searching for solutions online and it seems that a constant current LED driver could help with this problem, but I'm not sure how would I generate the wave and modulate the frequency from a PC in that case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

[image: circuit for one LED]

[image: oscilloscope luminance measures]

**Edit**: The LED's rise time has decreased significantly with @JackCreasey 's proposed solution:

[image: new luminance measures]

Comment: Too broad.  You have 2 or 3 separate issues here.  Split this up into separate questions.

Comment: How do you know the problem is not with your luminance measurement being slow rather than the LED drive? Let's see the LED **current** waveform.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, thank you for your comment. I'm not sure how to measure the LED current waveform, I'll look into it. I've done other measurements with a luminance meter and the luminance changes as a function of frequency, with higher frequencies yielding lower luminance, which is in agreement with the oscilloscope measurements. This difference can be perceived visually as well when you alternate between two frequencies.

Comment: You simply need a push-pull driver or a passive R pull up such that rise time= diode capacitance C*R=T.  If software is not fast enough for perfect symmetry, a simple VCO or relaxation oscillator at 2F or just a /2 FF.  This can be done for $2

Comment: @NickAlexeev I've edited the question, hopefully it's ok now

Comment: You can put a small resistor in series with the LED, dropping 100mV or so is enough. Watch out for ground issues from the 'scope if you have an earth in your circuit.

Comment: @NickAlexeev You need to take the hold off this question.   The problem you have is the very large capacitance of the LED. You need to drive the LED in CC mode, but minimize the on off voltage transitions for the device. I'll add a schematic as soon as the question of off hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a lot wrong with your thinking about your problem, it's just a problematic implementation.

In your schematic when you turn the transistor off the LM317 will stop conducting and pull the voltage up to almost the battery supply.

When you turn the transistor on you include the fall time of the transistor, the settling time of the regulator and the time it takes to charge the forward capacitance of the LED. These types of LEDs have rather large junction capacitance which can be problematic for constant current drivers.

What you need to do to operate the LED in a very fast mode is to ensure that only the current through it is switched, and minimize changes in the voltage across it.

The datasheet for your LED ( the [APG2C3-530](http://www.roithner-laser.com/datasheets/led_highsingle/apg2c3-530.pdf) ) is a bit lacking in detail, so I've clipped the important detail from a [350mA Green LED](http://www.sunledusa.com/products/spec/XZDG10X160S.pdf).

[image]

Here, in the left hand graph you see the forward voltage (Vf) of the LED vs current through the device.
In the right hand graph you see the luminous output versus current.
If instead of setting the LED current from zero to 350mA (in this example) we set the current from 1mA to 350mA we get a 1000:1 change in brightness. If this is sufficient for your needs then the circuit below can help you.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhVXlY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With M2 on the LM317 still provides 350 mA, but the voltage drop across R2 is only 2 V. 
When M2 turns off the current flows through the LED. There is a risetime as the LED junction charges, but since the voltage transient is much reduced (it is not rising from Zero) this time is reduced.
This circuit is very effective both for LEDs and Lasers, but typically the Vf slope of the laser is much steeper so the voltage transient less.

You should certainly see your risetime improve when driven by a 50% PWM signal.

There is enough detail in the schematic to run a simulation, but just be aware that the FET details are incorrect even though I show a viable part number.

**Update:** From the Op's comments a question was asked whether 6 LEDs in series could be driven.
IMO this would be closer to the upper voltage in for the LM317 than I would personally feel comfortable with. However you could comfortably run 4 in series (shown below).
The best solution may be to actually only run 3 in series and run two strings with two LM317.

I've added a string of resistors (R4 - R7) that mask the low current/Vf differences between devices, these may be optional.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqvWQb.png)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This is incredibly helpful! I have a few follow-up questions if that's ok. 
 1) A 1000:1 change in brightness means the LED is never truly off, just alternating between high and very low brightness? 
 2) The part in M2 seems to be no longer available, would [this](https://uk.farnell.com/2061415) part be a suitable replacement? 
 3) How can I calculate the correct value for the capacitor once I add all the LEDs? (ultimately I would like to connect the six 4V LEDs in series)
Many thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Maydel Glad to help  1) Yes    2) Yes   3) C1 is for regulator stability, there is no real calculation. 6* 4V(Vf) LED in series requires about 24 V ….so something around 30-36V Vsupply. For the LEDs to be 'off' then R2 would need to hold the voltage at about 12V at your selected current. You might also need to put 1K Ohm resistors across each LED to balance the charge retained. I'll add to the answer shortly.

Comment: Many thanks @JackCreasey! I've already ordered some of the components and hope to test this soon. I have one more question if that's ok (sorry to bother you again!)...

Comment: I've ordered this MOSFET transistor [DMN6068SE](https://uk.farnell.com/2061415) which should work with the Arduino 5V square wave since Vgs=1V; however, I would also like to test this circuit (if possible) with a sine-wave generator that operates between 0-2V. From the datasheet it seems that the gate voltage to drain current relation of the MOSFET is non-linear, so it looks like the output wouldn't be a sine wave? Is there a type of transistor that might be more suitable for that? Many thanks!

Comment: @Maydel Square wave is relatively easy, but sinusoidal drive of the LED much more challenging. You need to decide do you actually need sinusoidal light output or not? If you do not then you can use a somewhat simpler approach, but if you do, then you need to measure the optical output directly (PIN diode). Please describe your requirements.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, it took a while to get the components. I’ve finally tested it and it has reduced the rise time of the LEDs significantly. Thanks very much for your help! 
A square wave is fine for now. The main issue I'm having is that the LEDs are never off, which is vital for my application. You mentioned that “for the LEDs to be 'off' R2 would need to hold the voltage at about 12V at your selected current”. How can I calculate that for [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OX1eEqD17cYJ5ZuPy149dtRCn7n09A5r) circuit? It has 2 strings of 3 LEDs in parallel, so 1400mA-12V total.

Comment: @Maydel If there is any forward current through the LEDs in the 'off' condition they may produce optical output (whether 100:1 or 10000:1). Calculating the R values is simply the voltage you want divided by the current (good old Ohms Law). So at 12V and 1.4A this is 8.57 Ohms. a non standard value so you have to use multiple R's to build it. You could use a standard value and accept the voltage of course ….so an 8 Ohm would result in an 11.2V off condition. You can reduce the off voltage to get more 'off' but this will result in a definite slope to the turn on transition.

Comment: Thanks very much! I've tested with 12V by using multiple resistors and the transition time has increased indeed. I guess 10000:1 will have to do for now. Do you know of any other solutions for fast pulsing high power LEDs at 1:0 that I could look into for the longer term? Maybe a different type of LED would be more suitable? Or anything off-the-shelf even if it is a bit more expensive? I would appreciate any info even if it's just the "name" of what to look for. Many thanks!

Comment: @Maydel Can you explain why 10000:1 optical output range could be a problem, I simply can't see it. We are talking about 100 lm to 0.01 lm at worst. What could you possibly have that has this range of sensitivity?

Comment: The circuit I'm building is to test the human flicker fusion threshold in the periphery at high luminance. Even a very low output in the "off" period could be detected by a different kind of photoreceptive cell than the ones I'm targeting. It would mainly make the calculations and modelling afterwards more complicated and decrease the certainty of the results. That's why ideally I would need a contrast of 1 in addition to no changes in luminance for different frequencies (since the threshold depends on luminance); however, this has proven to be way more challenging than I initially thought :)

Comment: @Maydel Interesting, but even at 1000:1 you'd have changed from cone to rod sensitivity (so overall sensor sensitivity is down by 5:1 on the scotopic curve). https://telescope-optics.net/eye_intensity_response.htm You should capture the luminance at both on and off levels and determine exactly what the ratio of luminance is. You could use a microscope to examine the off state, I'm sure you'll find the optical output is much less than you think it is. http://alan.ece.gatech.edu/ECE3080/Lectures/ECE3080-L-11d-LEDs%20and%20Lasers.pdf